# Observar las conexiones de Mongodb en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

¿Existe alguna forma de observar los inicios y cierres de las conexiones que se realizan al servidor Mongodb?

Por ejemplo:
javascript

```
db.currentOp (true) .inprog.forEach (function (d) {if (d.client) print (d.client, d.connectionId)})
```

El problema de esto sería ineficiente y debería consultarse cada cierto intervalo de tiempo, y no detectaría rápidamente un cierre de conexión.

Nota: Estoy creando un sistema de descubrimiento de servicios de forma decentralizada.

Estaba observando el código fuente del [módulo SDAM](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-core/tree/master/lib/sdam), y he notado que solo solo observa las conexiones TCP que se establecen en el mismo proceso. ¿Podrían darme alguna sugerencia?

Comment: estás en Stack Overflow en español, deberías editar y traducir tu pregunta o bien eliminarla y realizarla en el sitio de idioma inglés.

Comment: Hola, este foro es en español, reformula la pregunta en español o publícala en [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)  en ingles